# How to determine if struct property has `nil` value using reflection in Go?

Tags: go, reflection

I am creating an app in Go that is supposed to receive a JSON and unmarshal it into different possible values.

To do this, I created a parent struct, that contains the possible JSON formats that the app will receive.

So the idea is to try to unmarshal the received JSON into each child struct and check if any of them didn't receive any values. If this is the case, then the app will set that struct to `nil` at a later point.

The problem is that when I try to use the `isNil()` method from Go's reflection, it doesn't work for a generic struct. It only works if I know the struct's format.

Here is an example ([playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/u9KmsEt8HlO)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type User struct {
    Username *string `json:"username,omitempty" required:"true"`
    Password *string `json:"password,omitempty" required:"false"`
}

type UserError struct {
    Error *string `json:"error,omitempty" required:"true"`
    Code  *int    `json:"code,omitempty" required:"true"`
}

type UserOrError struct {
    User      *User
    UserError *UserError
}

var userJson = `{ "username": "john@email.com", "password": "password" }`

func main() {
    user := &UserOrError{}
    data := []byte(userJson)

    types := reflect.TypeOf(user).Elem()
    values := reflect.ValueOf(user).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < types.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldType := types.Field(i)
        unmarshalledValue := reflect.New(fieldType.Type)

        err := json.Unmarshal(data, unmarshalledValue.Interface())
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        value := unmarshalledValue.Elem()
        fmt.Printf("Unmarshalled: %+v - hasValues: %v \n", value, hasValues(value))
        // Unmarshalled: &{Username:0x14000102110 Password:0x14000102120} - hasValues: true
        // Unmarshalled: &{Error:<nil> Code:<nil>} - hasValues: true
        values.Field(i).Set(value)
    }

    fmt.Printf("User: %+v - hasValues: %v\n", user.User, hasValues(user.User))
    // User: &{Username:0x14000102110 Password:0x14000102120} - hasValues: true
    fmt.Printf("UserError: %+v - hasValues: %v\n", user.UserError, hasValues(user.UserError))
    // UserError: &{Error:<nil> Code:<nil>} - hasValues: false
}

func hasValues(obj any) bool {
    var values reflect.Value
    if reflect.TypeOf(obj).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        values = reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    } else {
        values = reflect.ValueOf(obj)
    }

    for i := 0; i < values.NumField(); i++ {
        innerValue := values.Field(i)
        if innerValue.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !innerValue.IsNil() {
            return true
        } else if !innerValue.IsZero() {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

As you can see, `isNil()` works if I know the struct beforehand, so `hasValues` is `false` for the `UserError` struct, but if I call the same function using the generic struct that I created through `reflect.New` (`unmarshalledValue`), then `hasValues` always returns `true`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `unmarshaledValue` (as well as the result of `unmarshaledValue.Elem()`) is a value of type `reflect.Value` (which is full of non-nil unexported fields) that represents the actual value. But _represents_ != _is_. Try printing the type of the variable to see the difference, i.e. `fmt.Printf("%T\n", value)`.

Comment: Note also that for structs with _only comparable_ fields, you can use plain `==` to check if any of its fields were set (no need for reflection), e.g. `user.User == nil || *user.User = (User{})` will result in `true` if `user.User` is `nil` or all of its fields have the _zero value_.

Comment: Yes, I printed the value and there was a lot there, but I was hoping to find a way to get the underlying value...

Comment: Also, I know I can use `==`, but on the actual app, I won't know what is the type of the struct at compile time, because this is meant to be a library, so the user can create his own structs and ask for them to be unmarshaled. This is why I am using reflection.

Comment: *"but I was hoping to find a way to get the underlying value"* -- Then don't call `reflect.ValueOf()` and `TypeOf` on an instance of type `reflect.Value`, that's all there is to it. i.e. `hasValues(value.Interface())`. Or, inside `hasValues`, first check if `obj` is already a `reflect.Value` and _if it is_ don't call `ValueOf`/`TypeOf` on it (you can use type assertion for the check, e.g. `if rv, ok := obj.(reflect.Value); ok { ...`)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand, how can I check if the fields on an unknown struct are `nil`, if I don't use reflection?

Comment: Felipe my previous comment is about how to avoid the problem you have _while using reflection_.